# Import XML into MySql DB keeping leading zeros

Tags: mysql, xml, leading-zero

I have an XML file to import into a MySql db.
I have a node with a string with some leading zeroes; lenght is not always the same.
Once I import the file inside my DB, all leading zeros disappears... this is a big problem for me.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `scc_import` (
                  `ItemId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
                  `ItemName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
                  `TaxCode` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
                  ....
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is a node of my XML:

```
<database name="mydb">
  <table name="scc_import">
    <column name="ItemId">000053</column>
    <column name="ItemName">Grüne Olivenpaste Arbequina</column>
    <column name="TaxCode">WDR</column>
    ... all other fields ...
  </table>
  ... all other nodes ...
</database>
```

ItemId field, once imported, becomes 53 instead of 000053

Is there something I can write inside my XML or a small modification to my table that I can do to keep my zeroes ?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: How are you importing?

Comment: I'm importing the file via PhpMyAdmin v.5.6.44-86.0-log  
If there's no solution, I'll convert my XML into a standard SQL Import Query.